# syntax for calling a method on a member with multiple instances

Tags: c++11, inheritance, c++14

I the following case

```
template<typename T>
class base{
    public:
        void test(){}
};

template<typename T>
class helper{
    public:
        base<T> t;
};

template<typename T, typename ... Ts>
class holder: public helper<T>, helper<Ts>... {
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    holder<int, short, long> h;
    h.t.test(); // of course, error here
}
```

Which compiles until I try to refer to the ambiguous `t` of `holder<...>`. What would the syntax be to refer to a `t` of one of the specific inherited `helper`s?

---

P.S.

I Honestly have no idea how to title this question. If somebody could edit that, that'd be a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a class name qualifier like you usually would:

```
h.helper<int>::t.test();
```

It's bizarre syntax, to be sure, but it is no different from writing

```
foo.Base::member
```

to access a hidden base class member from a derived class instance.